# What have mustaches to do with typography

Tags: typography

It seems that mustaches is a recurring meme amongst creative people in areas of graphic design, typography etc.

I am referring to things like these t-shirts [[1](http://www.google.com/search?q=typography%20mustache%20t-shirt&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1440&bih=787)]

or these posters [[1](http://vi.sualize.us/view/vanity_one/de7266e75c8256a3683bcac661907625/)], [[2](http://seattlestyles.blogspot.com/2011/08/mustache-typography.html)], [[3](http://weheartit.com/entry/14289751/via/supperherox3)], [[4](http://classicallymodernnest.blogspot.com/2010/08/mustache-me.html)]

blog posts like these [[1](http://amperstache.wordpress.com/category/mustache/)]

as they directly mention typography for some reason.

Apparently there is some connection to characters "{" "}", although I am not too sure on that.

It all seemed a bit fetish-like to me (in a good funny way, though), although mentioning it here seemed to attract some negative responses from readers.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't have any idea what you are talking about. Could you provide some examples? And all in all this *does* sound a bit rant-y, non-constructive topic rather than a question; I hope you'll edit the question if your intentions were in good faith.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is an in-depth answer to this, but the meme is indeed real:  http://boingboing.net/2010/07/23/typographic-mustache.html

Comment: @koiyu, I added some evidence to my post, sorry you saw that in a negative light, I was rather curios and perplexed with this phenomena.

Comment: Down-voting without a comment is bad form.

Comment: What do cats have to do with Cheeseburgers? It's just a meme of the moment. Not really worthy of analysis.

Comment: I can haz mustache?

Answer (score 7):

The curly-brace-as-mustache goes back to the early days of ASCII emoticons. :-{) If I recall correctly, it's not specifically mentioned in the [Jargon File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon_File) (still a great read, by the way) but it certainly predates that document.

Like all fashions, mustaches have run the cycle of cool, then out of date, then quirkily antique, then in style again. We're in the "quirky" phase at the moment, from what I can tell, and the availability of thousands of digital typefaces allows those with the right sense of humor to play with it.

Comment: +1  I couldn't think of a way to say anything other than "because they look like mustaches!"

Comment: LOL! That's the truth!